# How to leave out some headings from table of contents in OpenOffice

Tags: libreoffice, openoffice, libreoffice-writer, table-of-contents

I'm writing my thesis in OpenOffice and would like to do the following. My thesis starts by pages which are not part of the document body - such as my abstracts, table of contents and so on. I still use headings on these pages, which makes them appear in the table of contents. What I would like to is to start my table of contents with the introduction numbered as page one. I.e. I need to leave out headings before introduction from the table of contents. How do I do this? I can restart numbering at the page where my introduction starts, but I'm unsuccessful in leaving out some of the headings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't use OpenOffice, but might it be possible to delete the entries you don't want from the TOC?
If it's possible, you'll still need to repeat this every time that you regenerate the TOC.

Another suggestion is to create other styles, identical to Heading 1-n, and use them instead.

Comment: Both of these solutions are far from perfect, but thanks for suggestions anyway.